# Perl DB interaction

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I just started using Perl. I am able to connect to my MySQL database, create tables and get query results using my Perl Script. I came across a task that involves "You MUST use the provided DB.pm for all database interaction, and you must use it as it is (DB.pm cannot be modified except for the connection settings)."
 What does that mean? Any one can guide me in the right direction ?

### DB.pm file contains the following code

```
package GUI::DB;

use strict;
use DBI;

use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(dbConnect query);

#
# dbConnect - connect to the database, get the database handle
#
sub dbConnect {

        # Read database settings from config file:
        my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
        my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn,
                '',
                '',
                                { RaiseError => 1 } 
    );

        return $dbh;

}

#
# query - execute a query with parameters
#       query($dbh, $sql, @bindValues)
#
sub query {
        my $dbh = shift;
        my $sql = shift;
        my @bindValues = @_;            # 0 or several parameters

        my @returnData = ();

        # issue query
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        if ( @bindValues ) {
                $sth->execute(@bindValues);
        } else {
                $sth->execute();
        }

        if ( $sql =~ m/^select/i ) {
                while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                        push @returnData, $row;
                }
        }

        # finish the sql statement
        $sth->finish();

        return @returnData;
}

__END__
```

---

Comment: It seems to be just a very simplistic wrapper for the DBI module. It serves no real purpose except obscuring some of the details, and preventing the database handle to be used as an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, it means, that in your code you must use something like this:

```
use GUI::DB;

my $dbh = dbConnect();
my $sql = qq{SELECT * FROM my_table};
my @data = query($sql, $dbh);
```

You interact with the database through the provided module.